# R - Conditional Substr from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, character, substring, substr

I need to substr from a column based on start and end locations. The start and end locations are derived from a character search.

For example, a single column in Dataframe with 3 rows:

```
'Bond, Mr. :James'
'Woman, Mrs. :Wonder'
'Hood, Mr. :Robin'
```

Expected Answer in Column 2 is:

```
'Mr.'
'Mrs.'
'Mr.'
```

I want to extract all strings in between ',' and ':' for column 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gsub(".*, | :.*", "", myvec)`

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
str_extract(x, 'Mr(s?).')
```

@akrun has a suggestion to help with more cases.

```
str_extract(myvec, '\\S+(?=\\s*:)')
```

By specifying non-space characters followed by one or more spaces and a colon, a variety of titles and honorifics will be captured by the regex pattern.

Comment: @akrun I find that most regex questions are limited by the OP's examples. If outlier examples exist, why post three examples of the same layout? By showing some variety, targeted help can occur.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps, I am hoping for more effort on the part of the seekers to better describe their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stringr package to perform common string operations like trimming, substrings, or extracting patterns:

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(str_sub(str_extract(x, ",[^:]*"), 2))
# [1] "Mr."  "Mrs." "Mr."
```